# Tree shaking not working for node package

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a node module that is generally shaped like this (simplifying for example's sake):

```
# color.js

export var red = '#f00';
export var yellow = '#ff0';
export var blue = '#00f';
```

```
# images.js

export var image1 = '<base64 string approximately ~ 500kb>';
export var image2 = '<base64 string approximately ~ 500kb>';
```

```
# index.js

// JavaScript tokens
import * as colorExport from './color';
import * as imagesExport from './images';

export var color = colorExport;
export var images = imagesExport;
```

And then in my Next.js app (also tested in Create React App) I import the value like this:

```
# Home

import { color } from 'my-module'

const Home = () => (
  <h1 style={{ color: color.red }}>Hello!</h1>
)

export default Home
```

This works fine. However, in both Next.js and Create React App, when I go to build the production-ready site EVERYTHING from `my-module` (`color` and `images`) is included and the final bundle size is a little greater than 1MB.

Now, if I change the import statement in Home to this:

```
import * as color from 'my-module/color'
```

Then the final bundle only includes the color values as I would expect. But I would like to not have to import so specifically. Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm pretty certain it doesn't like `var color = colorExport;`. Try using `export { colorExport as color }` instead

Comment: That worked — thanks! And is less disruptive than my change in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Refactoring `color` and `images` to have a default export rather than named exports and then also rewriting the way `index` import and exports fixed the problem.

E.g.

```
# color.js

export default {
  red: '#f00',
  yellow: '#ff0',
  blue: '#00f'
}
```

```
# index.js

export { default as color } from './color';
export { default as images } from './images';
```

Comment: Are constants from those object literals omitted during the build? I didn't think tree shaking would do that

Comment: Not `color.yellow` or `color.blue` if that's what you mean. That's another problem I have to figure out.

Comment: Though doing this works to import single named exports and seems acceptable: `import { image1 } from 'my-module/images'`

Comment: That should not work, but throw an exception. I guess your transpiler/bundler is being too lenient here, for backwards-compatibility with commonjs modules.